# Asp / ajax call web service and GET xml

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, soap

My code returns : interne server error

```
  var parameters = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
        "<soap:envelope xmlns:xsi='ttp://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
        "<soap:body>" +
        "<listeVille xmlns='http://..../b1'>" +     
        "<ville>"+ "Test" +"</ville>" +
        "</listeVille>" +
        "</soap:body>" +
        "</soap:envelope>";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _URL_SITE + "webservices/b1.asmx",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            SOAPAction: 'http://.../webservices/b1/ListeVille'            },
        success: function (xml) {
            alert('test');
            //var _xmldoc
            //_xmldoc = new activexobject("microsoft.xmldom");
            //_xmldoc.async = "false";
            //_xmldoc.loadxml(xml);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

And my web service :

```
<WebMethod(True)> Public Function ListeVille(ByVal ville As String) As System.Xml.XmlDocument

        Dim _xml As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim _hsh As New ParameterCollection

        Try
            _hsh.Add("@Ville", "")
            _xml.LoadXml(_hsh)
        Catch ex As Exception
            AjoutJournal(ex)
        End Try
        Return _xml
    End Function
```

I try to call my web service and get a xml file.
For information, don't focus on my function ListeVille, it returns the great value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an **Internal Server Error** which means that there is an Exception in your server Side Code.

If you enable the Remote Errors then you can see the errors on the remote machine. Otherwise, if you debug the code on the machine, you can see the exception Details.

Moreover, the usage of `XmlDocument.LoadXml` Method doesn't seem to be correct as posted in your question. The Parameter to the `LoadXml` is a String containing the XML document to load. Try to pass in a valid XML.  You can find more details on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i try to put this sentence :  

`code_xml.LoadXml("<Table><cp>47000</cp><commune>Agen</commune></Table>")`

I have the same pb. When i check on IE,  the content-type (return) : text/xml.

Comment: @FlorentD Try this working fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/hi4fDg. The problem was with your end tag. If you compare the unicode value it's not the same and hence it wasn't a valid XML and therefore parser was throwing an error.